# Refresh page when media query breakpoints are triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a bootstrap based layout that has 4 columns and two rows on large, 2 columns and 4 rows on small and 1 column and 8 rows on extra small sizes, and with some help I managed to build the script that manipulates the DOM when media query breakpoints are triggered to insert new row and hr divider between rows for smaller screen sizes;
This works well for adjacent MQ breakpoints, but I need to refresh the page when media query breakpoints are triggered to reset the DOM because the layout starts braking further down the media query breakpoints the window is resized.
I know how to refresh the page on window width resize, but this is impractical because it refreshes the page every time the window is resized, and I only need to trigger refresh on media query breakpoints. How do I do this?

Here is the script that I'm using to manipulate the dom:

```
    var $mainElem = $('.latest-posts'),
  $parent = $mainElem.parent(),
  $nav=$('.before-navigation')

if ($(window).width() < 768){     
  var $items = $mainElem.children(':gt(0)').detach()
  if ($items.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i = i + 1) {
      var $row = $('<div class="row latest-posts">').append($items.slice(i, i + 1));
      $nav.before('<hr class="small-article-divider">').before($row);

    }
  }
}else if ($(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).width() <= 970){     
  var $items = $mainElem.children(':gt(1)').detach()
  if ($items.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i = i + 2) {
      var $row = $('<div class="row latest-posts">').append($items.slice(i, i + 2));
      $nav.before('<hr class="small-article-divider">').before($row);

    }
  }
}else if($(window).width() > 970){
  var $items = $mainElem.children(':gt(3)').detach()
  if ($items.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i = i + 4) {
      var $row = $('<div class="row latest-posts">').append($items.slice(i, i + 4));
      $nav.before('<hr class="small-article-divider">').before($row);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Easier ways to do this. Look at how the [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) in boostrap work. Can have elements with clearfix in them that are visible/hidden at different breakpoints without having to change the dom

Answer (score 1):

Do what @charlietfl said. Find a better way to build the HTML/CSS. Manipulating the DOM like this is likely unnecessary. Changing the design to avoid page refreshing is acceptable in my opinion.

But, if you insist, set a variable for the `context`.

```
var context;
var $window = $(window);

// run this right away to set context
if ($window.width() <= 768) {
    context = 'small';
} else if (768 < $window.width() < 970) {
    context = 'medium';
} else {
    context = 'large';
}

// refresh the page only if you're crossing into a context
// that isn't already set
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(($window.width() <= 768) && (context != 'small')) {
        //refresh the page
        location.reload();
    } else if ((768 < $window.width()  < 970) && (context != 'medium')) {
        location.reload();
    } else if (context != 'large') {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Keep in mind to check for `resize` and `orientationchange` (jQuery supports these events, there are other libraries that can used, too).

Comment: I'm afraid responsive utilities won't do the task, so I absolutely need to be able to refresh the page on two breakpoints 768px and 970px in each direction. I think I understand the concept, but I can't get your code to work. Could you please elaborate some more?

Comment: So you have the function $window.resize(function(){}).... which listens to any resizing of the document window. It constantly checks the size and then when the certain breakpoints are hit ( when window size is 768px) it triggers that if statement and then you can probably call ($window.reload()?) or, window.location.reload(). Does that help clarify things a little?\